# SAP Cloud Foundry Application is currently unable to handle this request -

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

I have deployed the Multi target application to SAP Cloud Foundry account via SAP Web IDE. The cockpit shows the application is running. But when I open the link, the page doesn't load. I am using trial SCP account and I have deleted the expired CF trail sub-account and recreated a new one. Kindly help me solve this. Thanks. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi! Two things: a) this question is not related to the SAP Cloud SDK. b) Nonetheless, can you provide some logs? The application is definitely running, otherwise you would get a 404 instead of a 500. You can get logs either by using `cf logs <appname>` from your command line, or there should be a button "logs" somewhere in the Cloud Cockpit after navigating to the application (i.e. from where the second screenshot is taken).

Comment: Probably if you had expired trial and re-created it, you didn't assigned app quota to the new one. As Dennis said, we need the logs